# Reading numbers from a .txt/input file and printing a triangle in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package classicTriangle;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class classicTriangle {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("c:/eclipse/numbers");
    Scanner scan = null;
    String str[];
    int s1=0,s2=0,s3=0;
    try 
    { 
        Scanner file = new Scanner( new File("c:/eclipse/numbers"));
        String line;
        while((line=file.nextLine())!=null)
        {
            str = line.split(" ");

            if(str.length==3)
            {
                try
                {
                    s1 = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
                    s2 = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
                    s3 = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);

                    if(s1+s2>=s3 && s2+s3>=s1 && s1+s3>=s2)
                    {
                        if(s1==s2 && s2==s3) System.out.println("Equilateral");
                        else if(s1==s2 || s2==s3 || s3==s1) System.out.println("Isosceles");
                        else System.out.println("Scalene");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    }

    }
```

I am getting a duplicate local variable at the line

**" Scanner file = new Scanner( new File("c:/eclipse/numbers"));"**

I am a noob to this, and honestly cannot figure it out. Any advice/input would be great.

Comment: change the name of `Scanner file = new Scanner( new File("c:/eclipse/numbers"));` to something else and then update where it is used

Comment: Although I don't think you are useing `File file = new File("c:/eclipse/numbers");` - so that could be deleted, but there again, you have a unused `Scanner scan = null;`  Also do not silently swallow exceptions **print** them out

Comment: scary wombat, i deleted those two lines. All errors subsided, but when i run it i am not getting any output.

Comment: probably throwing an exception which you are not printing

Comment: how would one solve that?

Comment: It's a good idea in the testing phase to always include `e.printStackTrace()` in `catch` blocks, so you know what exceptions may have occurred. Currently, you're silently ignoring exceptions by catching them, then doing nothing.

Comment: scar wombat, your recommendation worked. Thank you for providing that input. I renamed file variable used in the scanner class to read the file, and deleted the file file = new file("") above it, and was able to tweak it and get an output. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You defined `File file` earlier, so that name is taken when you define `Scanner file`. Change one of them and everywhere you reference it.

Note that a `try` block doesn't have its own local variables; it shares those of the parent section.

Comment: sir, where would the best placement of this try block be? above the variables?

Comment: @AK47 The try block can go wherever you'd like it to; where you have it is fine if it fits your purposes (I would, however, follow Scary Wombat's several recommendations). I mentioned it to point out that variables declared before the try block still exist within it, which was causing the original error.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Im still stuck on running this for the proper output. thanks for the input, though

Comment: abemeister, if i am opening the same file that i am reading, will changing the name of one complicate that?